# Why does interrupt occur when counter reaches Compare value and not Auto Reload Register?

Tags: interrupt, stm32

Why does interrupt occur when counter reaches Compare value and not Auto Reload Register?

Comment: need more detail on which chip and which timer.

Comment: You have configured it to do what it is doing, if you want it to do something different then configure it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different types of interrupts in STM32. Capture Compare interrupt and Timer Overflow/Update/Reload interrupt. Check your NVIC to identify which interrupts are enabled.
You may find [this lecture](http://www.k-space.org/Class_Info/STM32_Lec5.pdf) helpful.